# InAppBilling crashes on startup

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm trying to make an app that I can get a simple implementation of in app purchases. I've been falling this guide http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Integrating_Google_Play_In-app_Billing_into_an_Android_Application_%E2%80%93_A_Tutorial

but it's fraught with probably outdated information and neglects to include all the names of the packages you need to download from the SDK manager. 
The main errors I had from this program were seemingly reference errors like I had not imported a certain library or compatibility files were missing. I managed to resolve all of them in eclipse and there are no errors when I run the code but trying it on a device or in the VM, the app crashes when I try to run it there.

I excluded the key you need for the google play connection for obvious reasons.

```
package com.a.inappbilling;

import com.a.inappbilling.util.IabHelper;
import com.a.inappbilling.util.IabResult;
import com.a.inappbilling.util.Inventory;
import com.a.inappbilling.util.Purchase;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;


public class InAppBillingActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_in_app_billing);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.in_app_billing, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_in_app_billing,
                container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}

private Button clickButton;
private Button buyButton;

@Override 
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    buyButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buyButton);
    clickButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.clickButton);   
    clickButton.setEnabled(false);

    String base64EncodedPublicKey = 
            "key here";

    mHelper = new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);

    mHelper.startSetup(new 
            IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
                 public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) 
             {
                       if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                         Log.d(TAG, "In-app Billing setup failed: " + 
                    result);
                       } else {             
                         Log.d(TAG, "In-app Billing is set up OK");
                   }
                     }
    });
}

public void buttonClicked (View view)
{
    clickButton.setEnabled(false);
    buyButton.setEnabled(true);
}

private static final String TAG = "com.a.inappbilling";
IabHelper mHelper;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Add permission to your Manifest file

```
 <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
```

also add to your Manifest file under the `Application` node

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Also just verify you have added `InAppBillingActivity.java` to your Manifest file.